# VB.NET Input method editor

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, ime

I think it's a difficult question but how to make a custom IME like Google IME that edits the input method while typing in any software? I need a starting way to do this...

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Look at the accepted answer on this [Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434048/how-do-you-use-ime)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the Windows API, see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190000/en-us) for using it with VB (you should use visual studios code analysis, because the style of this example is very "old-school") and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for some keyboard specific API things.

The next thing is to get in the windows message loop, [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/get-in-the-loop-control-your-vb-apps-window-messages-with-subclassing/1055957) is another article.