# Displaying Input method editor on Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I am working on a C++/Qt application.The application should also accept text written in Japanese language.I could also use Qt way of using the input method enabled attribute but for some reason I want the OS specific input editor window(see screenshot)

[image: Input method editor on Windows]

I found this link which talks about activating the input method manager:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752003.aspx

My question is :
Is the above procedure the right way to display the OS Input method editor?

Comment: [Near dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434048/179910). The short answer is that what you've found is very old, and more capable input was added in Windows 2000.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Are you suggesting to use Text services Framework?I have already been through this link and msdn links which is it provides for using Input Method Manager are not really helpful for a novice in Windows programming

Comment: TSF is a pain, but it works. One of the formerly documented ones quit working as of Windows Vista (but offhand, I don't remember which).